# How to get multiple drop-down box value using J-Query

Tags: php, jquery

I have generated drop-down box using loop. Now I want to get all value using J-Query for pass these value for insertion through Ajax.

My HTML CODE is:

```
<select name="travel[]" id="travel[]"  >
     <option   value="1">Car</option>
<select>
<select name="travel[]" id="travel[]"  >
     <option   value="2">Train</option>
<select>
<select name="travel[]" id="travel[]"  >
     <option   value="3">Bus</option>
<select>
```

After click on Save button, how to collect all values of travel?

Comment: IDs must be unique FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var data = $('select[name="travel[]"]').map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(data);    // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

This will return you an **array** with the value for all the dropdowns.

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4bD7/)

Comment: To do that, he may as well define `data = [ '1', '2', '3' ];`, because there's no way for the user to change their selection...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you define three `<select>` elements with an index-based name, each containing a single `<option>`. You do know that a `<select>` element is exactly that - it gives the user a **selection**?

With your current markup, the user doesn't get a choice about their selection - rather, `travel[]` will always be an array containing: `1,2,3`.

You'd be better to modify your markup as follows:

```
<select name="travel" id="select_travel">
     <option value="1">Car</option>
     <option value="2">Train</option>
     <option value="3">Bus</option>
<select>
```

Now you can easily access the value using:

```
$('#select_travel').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are making name and id both as array type... i think one will enough if you really want to use array type.... then make **id** as unique for all...

```
  <select name="travel[]" id="abc">
  </select>

  <select name="travel[]" id="def">
  </select>

  <select name="travel[]" id="xyz">
  </select>
```

now you can access dropdown list easily..

```
   $("#abc").val();
   $("#def").val();
   $("#xyz").val();
```

or else you can define uniq class for them if you really want array type **id** and **name**

```
   <select name="travel[]" id="travel[]" class="abc">
  </select>

  <select name="travel[]" id="travel[]" class="xyz">
  </select>
```

and try like this...

```
   $(".abc").val();
   $(".xyz").val();
```

hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

you should try js like-

```
var selectOption=$('#select_travel').val()
var Id=selectOption.getAttribute('id');
var name=selectOption.getgetAttribute('id');
```

now you can take output on button click